# Implementing an OTP Auth on Symfony project

Tags: symfony

I have implemented an OTP auth check on my symfony project, and I'd like to check with you if I'm doing the right thing or if I can do something better. I have some doubt.
I'm using an API based project, so my backend is  API Platform based. I'm using Lexik bundle to handle JWT Token.

This is how I'm approaching.

First of all, I have a sub on CheckPassportEvent, to perform some check ( is user active? ).
If all is OK, I have a sub on lexik_jwt_authentication.on_authentication_success; in this sub, I generate a secure code that I send via SMS to the user authenticated.
In this sub I set the output that will be rendered using:

```
$event->setData([some stuff]);
```

The first part of login ends here.

When the user enter the secure code, I check the code and return a json with a JWT using Lexik bundle.

Apparently all is working fine but there is something I don't like.

In the first step, the symfony LoginSuccessEvent is raised after the OTP is generated and sent, and I have no way , actually, to avoid it because there is no way to stop the event propagation.
I think that I should raise this event ( LoginSuccessEvent ) at the end of OTP validation ( after the user use the OTP ), not before.

I 'd like to stop symfony auth event process, but I don't understand how I can do this.
I could throw an Exception during a CheckPasswordPEvent, to stop the login, but I'dn't raise an exception, because this is not an exception.

Any Idea?